# display difference between array and object in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am working on an appointment booking app. I have the scheduled saved in the database with values start and end for each day of the week. When a date is selected, a drop-down will display with the schedule broken down in 15-minute intervals for that day. Here is a snippet from my code:

```
$begin = new DateTime("$start");
$end   = new DateTime("$end");
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('15 min');
$times    = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

<select name="time">
<option value="">Select Time</option>
foreach ($times as $time) { ?> <option value=" <?php echo $time->format('H:i'), "\n";?>">
<?php echo $time->format('H:i'), "\n"
     ;
}
?> </option>
```

I also have another array of start times from a query of the database of appointments on the selected day for example

```
SELECT `stime` FROM `book` WHERE DOV="2019-09-19"
```

returns a value of

```
13:00:00
14:00:00
15:30:00
```

How can I compare the items in my first object to this array to not display these times in drop down when running the foreach loop?

Comment: Do you need to compare value from `<select></select>` with array from sql when user submits it to the server?

Comment: No i am comparing values from sql query  $query ="SELECT * FROM book WHERE DOV = '" . $_POST["dov"] . "'";

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `foreach` loop, you can check to see if the date string is one of the values inside the array returned from the SQL call. Only if it is *not* in the array would you then `echo` the result. To accomplish this, I would recommend using the [`in-array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function.

An example is below. You may have to do some small tweaks to get it working in your code.

```
// Before this, you'll need to initialize the array of returned values
// from your DB. In my example, I'll use $time_array for the array.
foreach ($times as $time) {
    $time_string = $time->format('H:i');
    if (!in_array($time_string, $time_array)) {
        echo '<option value="{$time_string}">';
    }
}
```